# Can I remove zone.js package or whatever it is from a angular/nativescript PWA project and not break the project

Tags: angular, nativescript, progressive-web-apps, zone.js

I was wondering if it is possible to exclude the zone.js dependency from  nativescript/angular pwa app.

Comment: Zone.js is needed for change detection. Is there any particular reason why you would want to do so?

Comment: I am having error zone already loaded when I running the app on android (device or emulator). All suggestions I have found have not solved ny problem.  I am running with angular 9.1.0 on windows 8. Any ideas on how to resole this anyone. "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.0",
    "@angular/cli": "9.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.0",
    "@nativescript/schematics": "9.0.0",
    "@nativescript/tslint-rules": "~0.0.5",